# how to select when you're doing group_by in ecto?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have a table activity that has fields as following

```
user_id
role_id
cost
inserted_at
updated_at
deleted_at
```

So using ecto query I have written a query like this

```
from t in activity, where: t.id == ^id, group_by: [t.user_id, t.role_id], select: %{inserted_at: t.inserted_at}
```

Since I can not use select without using an aggregate function. So what I need is that I need to choose the last element which is inserted for inserted_at field and its not possible to use aggregate on this. What are my options?

how can I achieve this?

also is there any alternative for group_by and I can achieve the same thing as group_by

Answer (score 0):

You are after [`max/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#max/1) because the last would have the maximal date.

```elixir
from t in activity,
  where: t.id == ^id,
  group_by: [t.user_id, t.role_id],
  select: %{inserted_at: max(t.inserted_at)}
```

---

When one needs to retrieve the `cost` for the max `inserted_at`, the following hack might be helpful

```elixir
query = 
  from t in Activity,
  where: t.id == ^id,
  group_by: [t.user_id, t.role_id], 
  select: %{
    inserted_at_with_cost:
      max(fragment("concat(?, ?)", t.inserted_at, t.cost))
  }
```

`concat` will convert `inserted_at` into `iso8601` string which is naturally ordered. The only thing left would be to transform the result with

```elixir
  for %{inserted_at_with_cost: value} <- Repo.all() do
    # 2021-10-15 14:59:46.772031
    <<inserted_at::binary-size(26), cost::binary>> = value
    %{inserted_at: inserted_at, cost: cost}
  end
```

Comment: Hi. I used this but I need to do the same thing for the cost field also. And using max will just result me maximum cost value which will be present there. Is there any other solution ?

Comment: Use subquery to group and `select cost, inserted_at sort by inserted_at desc limit(1)` from it then.

Comment: Can you give me example for this query?

Comment: basically, I want to understand which query will be a part of the subquery?

Comment: I could not figure out the subquery, but I have posted the hack solving the issue.

Comment: I don't think this will work. I need the last element for both fields. I think you're combining both of them. Am I right?

Comment: but I can use this for just inserted_at maybe

Comment: I don’t follow anymore. If you need `max(cost), max(inserted_at)`, these will be items from two different records, just use two aggregates. If you want the `cost` for the latest `inserted_at`, the hack above will surely do.

Comment: But max(cost) will give me the maximum amount present in the table, right?  I don't want that. I just want the last value which is inserted for just the cost. Let's not do the inserted_at field right now.

Comment: For this, my solution perfectly works.

Comment: How concat will work on the cost. and the cost is an integer value. It's giving me a max element here. which I don't want